# SSIS package to Insert flat file data to two different tables

Tags: ssis

I want to insert flat file data to two different sql table.But some additional field coming from flat file should be inserted to other table on the basis of indicator field but the usual field coming should be inserted into the regular table.
The other issue,the additional field to be inserted cannot be inserted directly because of no column mapping.

eg:

```
1234 056 Y Tushar
5678 065 N
```

So 1234 056 should be inserted to regular table but indicator Y tells us that Tushar should be inserted to other table.

But the table in which I want to Insert Tushar cannot be done directly as it does not have 1234 column name.

For indicator N also it should get inserted normally in the base table.

So what I did was I used a conditional split and then used ole db command but it it inserting multiple records in the table.

Answer (score 3):

If you put a `Multicast` task right after your flat file source, you can create extra copies of your data set. Then you can use one copy to insert into Regular Table, and then you can put your `Conditional Split` on the second copy.

Your data flow would then look like this:
[image]

In my `Flat File Source` I defined four columns:
[image]

The `Multicast` doesn't need any configuration, and I assume the `Regular Table` destination isn't giving you the trouble. So next, you'd create the Indicator check with a `Conditional Split` task. Check for a value of `Y` like this:
[image]

Then just map whichever available columns you want to insert into `Other Table`. I chose the second column (I called mine `Seq`) and the `Name` column. You may have these named differently.
[image]